# Restrict Access To index.php - Apache

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

so I want to restrict access to my `index.php` file when the request comes with parameters. For example:

- `https://example.com?param1=value1` (Restrict/deny access)
- `https://example.com` (Allow access and load website normally)

Is there any way I can do this with a `.htaccess` file?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite, near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^param1=value1$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ - [F]
```

This will return a 403 Forbidden if either of the following URLs are requested:

- `/?param1=value1`
- `/index.php?param1=value1`

Note that this matches the query string (URL parameters) *exactly* as stated in your example. Anything else will be permitted.

**UPDATE**

> how would I deny access if any parameters exist?

In this case, you can change the *condition* to simply match *anything*. That is *something*, but not *nothing*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
```

The dot (`.`) matches any character.

Comment: Great, but how would I deny access if any parameters exist? For example: https://example.com/?param1 (Deny access)

Comment: In that case, the `RewriteCond` directive can be simplified. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =^param1=.+$ 
RewriteRule ^ /errors/no.access.html
```

Comment: How would I go about denying the website if any parameters existe in the URL?

Comment: Replace line2 with RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =^.+=.+$

Comment: You can't match the query string with the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, you need to use the `QUERY_STRING` variable. But your `RewriteRule` directive matches _everything_, not just `index.php` (in the document root). And you would need to make sure that `/errors/no.access.html` returned the appropriate HTTP status code (403 probably), otherwise it will be a normal 200 OK status.