# htaccess rule to protect against malicious post requests to WordPress index.php?pubkey=

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I've been looking at a log created by a WordPress plugin called Bad Behavior and in it there are many entries from different IP addresses at various intervals during the day that are requesting the following URL:

`POST www.example.com/index.php?pubkey=b13bdb8297326599cf86aj25274e6a0c&bvTime=1549500166&bvVersion=0.1&bvMethod=getdata&sha1=true&sig=53fb643e40685ed89aa6754483b0a0d06bf1e63d0`

The part of the URL that remains the same is `/index.php?pubkey=` then the rest is different for the other entries in the log.

What I am looking to do if it's possible, is to block those post requests via the `.htaccess` in the root directory.

While researching I found this answer here: [Restrict Access To index.php - Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/918566/restrict-access-to-index-php-apache)

But since I don't really understand how to build directives correctly in the `.htaccess` file, I don't want to add something in there that can potentially block legitimate traffic or cause other problems.

Also while searching I found this piece of information at https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/ but they warn you that using the following rule can be problematic if the website is not static and or uses forms, which this particular website does.

```
#deny all POST requests
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

So with that said, I hope enough information was added here that can help someone to help me find an answer to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is indeed very similar to the [question you linked to](https://serverfault.com/questions/918566/restrict-access-to-index-php-apache).

However, one question I would ask is, do you need to specifically target POST requests? Why not any request (GET or POST) that starts`/index.php?pubkey=`? Or does this carry some other meaning in WordPress?

In which case, you can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pubkey=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [F]
```

No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper. No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive as that is no doubt set later in the file.

---

To specifically target POST requests then you can add another condition, as you did in your example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pubkey=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [F]
```

---

> **UPDATE:** it didn't work as I was expecting, since I was able to load the page by visiting `www.example.com/index.php?pubkey=`

This could happen if the above directive is in the wrong place in the `.htaccess` file and is conflicting with other directives. It needs to be at the very top of the `.htaccess` file, before any existing mod_rewrite directives.

> After some trial and error this is what blocked me completely, it works but I don't understand why, can you please explain the difference between what you gave me and this?
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (pubkey=.*) [NC]
> RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

This is far more general and blocks much more than just the URL stated in your question (possibly too much). These directives block *any* URL-path that contains `pubkey=` (case-insensitive) *anywhere* in the query string. So, it will block the following URLs (in addition to the URL stated above):

- `example.com/foo/bar?pubkey=xyz`
- `example.com/foo/bar/baz?abc=1&xyz=2&pubkey=`
- `example.com/foo/bar/baz?def=2&xyz=3&PuBkEy=xyz`

These directives can be simplified:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pubkey= [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

No need to *capture* the `RewriteRule` *pattern* or *CondPattern*. The regex `pubkey=` is the same as `pubkey=.*`. The `L` flag is not required when the `F` flag is used. And as mentioned above, no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive or use the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: To better understand your answer I looked up what this character meant ^, the definition I found is "Denotes the beginning of a regex (regex = regular expression) test string. That is, begin argument with the proceeding character.".

With that said, would it be better to flip the order of the lines you wrote so the htaccess file looks at the pieces of that directive in order, or that order is not important?

Also I don't know if targeting the POST request exclusively is good, bad or indifferent to be honest. 

Thanks for your answer btw I am testing it right now, will post results soon.

Comment: Yes, it's a regex (the same as used by many programming languages... PHP, JavaScript, C# etc.). Strictly speaking `^` denotes the start of the _string_ that the regex matches against. (It doesn't necessarily denote the start of the _regex_.) You can't "flip the order of the lines". They are already in the most efficient form. The `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (regex) is processed _before_ the `RewriteCond` directive that precedes it. Only when the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches are the preceding conditions processed.

Comment: I tested further over the weekend and this are the results. I went with your suggestion and eliminated the POST Request_Method to target anything with pubkey=, however it didn't work as I was expecting, since I was able to load the page by visiting  www.example.com/index.php?pubkey=

After some trial and error this is what blocked me completely, it works but I don't understand why, can you please explain the difference between what you gave me and this? Thanks!

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (pubkey=.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: That perhaps suggests you put the directive in the wrong place, or there is a conflict with existing directives? I've updated my answer addressing the points you've raised.

Comment: You are correct about the location. Initially I added the directives all the way on the top per your suggestion, I then moved it down further while troubleshooting and enclosed it with that wrapper. Thank you so much for your suggestions with this issue, also your explanations of the different options in the directives were really helpful, you thought me more than one new trick. With your assistance I call this a resolved issue, and I hope that your answer can help someone else in the future. Thank you again MrWhite!